# PHPStorm and magic methods

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpstorm

I am using PHPStorm and have written a class that utilises the SimpleXML class. Everything is fine, except when I traverse an XML string I will get "Undefined Property" warnings.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); //Returns SimpleXML Element

echo $xml->childElement; //PHPStorm reports "Undefined Property
```

I believe this is because the magic properties are not properly defined in PHPStorm. Is anyone aware of a nice little work around? It annoys me because I am pedantic about having nice clean code (and IDE) and having warnings come up on a class is just awful!

Comment: If you were to annotate your $xml variable as "var SimpleXMLElement", then I would expect the IDE to then be able to recognize its type and allow for autocompletion of the methods/properties of a SimpleXMLElement object.  However, this further assumes that the IDE itself has such a SimpleXMLElement class specified in its "PHP internals" code.  Eclipse PDT (Indigo) does *not* seem to have it  :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I've solved it. If I encapsulate the nodes inside curly braces as strings, PHPStorm will ignore these.

```
echo $xml->{'Parent'}->{'ChildElement'};
```

This has the advantage of being consistent if you encounter an XML tag with a hyphen, for instance. `$xml->{'Parent-Node'}`

Comment: It would be a nice feature to allow marking certain classes as containing dynamic properties (`SimpleXMLElement`, `stdClass`, `Zend_View_Interface`, etc) which would cause PhpStorm to ignore properties it didn't know about.

Comment: Let me get this straight - you're writing less-readable code so that you can avoid squiggly lines in your IDE, even though functionally it doesn't create any problems?

Comment: The answer is completely wrong and encourages bad practice: I agree with @Oddman that you just show errors prone code to suppress IDE warning. You can suppress a warning with ```/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedFieldInspection */``` annotation.

Answer (score 10):

I have not found a work-around so far but just creating a type with the properties in question and var-type-hinting the variable:

```
class myXmlStoredValueObject {
     /* @var string */
     public $childElement;
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); //Returns SimpleXML Element

/* @var $xml myXmlStoredValueObject */

echo $xml->childElement;
```

Naturally this is not always applicable / practicable, there is a cheat with `stdClass`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); //Returns SimpleXML Element

/* @var $xml stdClass */

echo $xml->childElement;
```

You don't need to declare any concrete type to make the hint disappear.

There are other deficiencies, too, you will still run into issues with`foreach` e.g., where you need to var-type-hint again.

Comment: Newer Phpstorm versions don't need this any longer.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the annoying warning you have several options:

1) Clear and readable:
**Define a stub-class somewhere in your project:**

```
class myXmlPhpRepresentation {
   /** @var string */
   public $childElement;
   /** @var number */
   public $anotherXmlProperty;
}
```

You don't need to require the class, just have it in the
project folder for IDE to index.
Then just use PhpDoc to "mix" that class with SimpleXMLElement:

```
/** @var myXmlPhpRepresentation|SimpleXMLElement $xml */
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo $xml->childElement;
```

It's a good practice: you will have a properly defined and readable php representation of your xml,
which will help with code autocompletion and remove the warning.

2) **Suppress the very warning on the code line:**

```
 /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedFieldInspection */
 echo $xml->childElement;
```

Alt+Enter on the warning -> Inspection ... options -> Suppress for statement

Not a very clean way, but the inspection will help you on the rest of the project.

3) **Disable the whole inspection.**

I guess it's a bad practice, but some inspections may be opinionated.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHPStorm is not compiling your Code "on the Fly" it doesnt know what's in "$string" if you loaded that String from a extern source.

You can look into the Plugin Repository if there's something that helps you out:

http://plugins.intellij.net/?webide