# How to get intellisense working with phpStorm when passing object to function or iterating

Tags: php, function, intellisense, phpstorm, code-hinting

I have an object with getters and setters but I'm loosing intellisense on that object when I pass it to a function or while iterating through a array of these objects.

For example:

```
...
$personA = new Person(..);
$age = $personA->getAge();  // intellisense works.

$personArray = array($personA, $personB, .. );
foreach($personArray as $aPerson){
   $aPerson->getAge();   //  no intellisense here
}

doSomething($personA); 



function doSomething($person){
   $person->getAge()         //  no intellisense here
   ...
}
```

What am I missing here?

Do I need to make a change to code(casting.. etc), Missing a phpStorm setting?
Maybe it's not possible?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For the first `foreach` case it is not (yet) possible out of the box, however you can typically hint that:

```
$personArray = array($personA, $personB, .. );
foreach ($personArray as $aPerson) {
   /* @var $aPerson Person */
   $aPerson->getAge();  // now with code-completition
}
```

Which is doing the type-hinting on the variable that is taking the iteration. Alternatively you can also do the type-hinting on the array variable:

```
/* @var $personArray Person[] */
$personArray = array($personA, $personB, .. );
foreach ($personArray as $aPerson) {
    $aPerson->getAge();  // now with code-completition
}
```

For your second case, you can add PHP type-hinting (which I recommend):

```
function doSomething(Person $person) {
   $person->getAge() //  now with code-completition
   ...
}
```

This also ensures that you can only pass values that are of that type. See as well [*Type Hinting <sup>Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/language.oop5.typehinting) and [*Interfaces <sup>Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/language.oop5.interfaces).

The other solution for the second case is to also document the parameter in the docblock of the function:

```
/**
 * @param Person $person
 */
function doSomething($person) {
   $person->getAge() //  now with code-completition
   ...
}
```

---

Some Related Answers:

- [Is there a way to make PhpStorm's autocomplete “go deeper”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7619837/367456)
- [PHPStorm and magic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666087/367456)
- [How do I make my PHP IDE understand Dependency Injection Containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6395761/367456)

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks, this was driving me crazy!

Comment: Thanks .. it saves me lot of time.

Answer (score 9):

While the PPHDoc blocks from [@hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre) answer is working in PHPStorm, the correct form would be type followed by variable name like this

```php
/** @var Person $aPerson */
```

and that

```php
/** @var Person[] $personArray */
```

These will work in PHPStorm and phpDocumentor.

Source: http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html